# Could not post data to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post some data to the php but i could not send anything and see where the problem is.The codes looks fine to me.In other words, i could not reach inside of if statement.Codes;

```
<form method="post" action="home.php" name="home" id="home">           
    <label for="in_come">enter something: </label><input type="text" name="in_come" id="in_come" /><br/>
```

```
<?php
echo "outside if";
if(isset($_POST['in_come']))
{
    echo "inside if";
    $income = $_POST['in_come']; 

    $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO income (income) VALUES ('".$in_come."')");   
    if ($registerquery)
    {
        echo "sended";
    }                           
}       
?>
```

Comment: Your code was incorrectly formatted.  Highlight all code and ctrl-k to make it a code block or use the `{}` button.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I think while trying to send codes, i accidently delete something

Comment: is echo"outside if"; working?

Comment: yes it is working well but not inside one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `echo "inside if";` is not working,
 try

```
if (isset($_POST['in_come']) && ($_POST['in_come'] != ""))
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['in_come']))
```

Comment: I think i solved it now,by deleting everything and recoding them with your codes

Comment: good.. you have to do correction which Micheal said too.. Else it wont enter into database.

Answer (score 2):

You assign `$income` but later you use `$in_come` in your query

```
$income = $_POST['in_come']; 

$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dersler (income) VALUES ('".$in_come."')");
//-----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Incidentally, this won't hurt your PHP, but the you also have used `<label for='income'>` while the input's `id` is actually `id='in_come'`.

To debug the contents of your POST and verify that `$_POST['in_come']` is set, use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Do you have a `<input type='submit'>`?

Comment: yea i had that but did not appear in here