# Undefined index error

Tags: php, html

i am trying to Post something but keep getting Undefined index error. I have encountered this problem before and using  if(isset($_POST['in_come']) solved my previous problem. But, now it does not. What can cause this problem? Everything seems correct.Html posts an input and php should have gotten it
Thanks

Comment: Having your code regarding this issue would help greatly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7101015/165154 Is this not the same question you just asked there?

Comment: At least a sample code snippet is required to properly diagnose the error you're encountering. Maybe try dumping out the entire $_POST variable to see the item you're after exists as one of the keys?

Comment: yea:D i could not formate it correctly.So asked it with very few information again:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by you trying to access an array index that doesn't exist. E.g:

```
$foo = array('bar');
echo $foo[99999];
```

That means you have a logic error somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by passing an invalid index to an array, whether it be a string or integer index. Using `if(isset($_POST['in_come'])` should return false if it doesn't exist though, and not throw an error. If you would post your code, people could be more helpful